# Importar un esquema de UI en PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Tengo un esquema de un StyleSheet de PyQt en un documento aparte que quiero importar dentro de una UI.

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
style_sheet_file = qc.QFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'stylesheets', 'scheme.qss'))
        style_sheet_file.open(qc.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.setStyleSheet(qc.QLatin1String(style_sheet_file.readAll()))
```

Sin embargo, recibo el siguiente error en PySide:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QLatin1String'

¿Qué otras alternativas podría usar para hacer tal acción?

He intentado :

```
#style_sheet_file = mc.internalVar(usd=1) + 'digital_tutors\stylesheets\scheme.py'
#self.setStyleSheet(style_sheet_file)
```

y me corre sin error, pero no me importa el archivo dentro de la UI. Es decir, es como si `setSyleSheet` estuviese vacío.

Answer (score 1):

```
   style_sheet_file = mc.internalVar(usd=1) + 'digital_tutors\stylesheets\scheme.txt'
    with open(style_sheet_file,'r') as styleSheet:
        data = str(styleSheet.read())
        self.setStyleSheet(data)
```

asi he resuelto mi problema.